# how to draw on canvas with out using ink-manager in Metro style apps

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I want to draw a shape on canvas, that should be treated as shape , means after I drawn I can able to select , move, delete from canvas.It could be an alphabet or number or circle , which could be anything we can draw on canvas like MSPaint.

And I don't want to use the inkmanager because which is not recommended for UWP  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.inking.inkmanager.aspx). 
 Is this possible to do without using inkmanage. 
   here is the code on pointer moved on canvas

```
void AddPencil(Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PenID != 0)
        {
            PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(_drawCanvas);

            CurrentContactPoint = pt.Position;
            X1 = PreviousContactPoint.X;
            Y1 = PreviousContactPoint.Y;
            X2 = CurrentContactPoint.X;
            Y2 = CurrentContactPoint.Y;

            if (Distance(X1, Y1, X2, Y2) > 2.0)
            {
                Line line = new Line()
                  {
                      X1 = X1,
                      Y1 = Y1,
                      X2 = X2,
                      Y2 = Y2,
                      StrokeThickness = 5,
                      Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Violet)
                  };
                _drawCanvas.Children.Add(line);
            }


            PathFigure pthFigure = new PathFigure();
            pthFigure.StartPoint = PreviousContactPoint;
            BezierSegment bzSeg = new BezierSegment();
            Point p1 = new Point();
            p1.X = X1;
            p1.Y = Y1;
            Point p2 = new Point();
            p2.X = X2;
            p2.Y = Y2;
            bzSeg.Point1 = p1;
              bzSeg.Point2 =p2;
              bzSeg.Point3 = CurrentContactPoint;

            PathSegmentCollection myPathSegmentCollection = new PathSegmentCollection();
            myPathSegmentCollection.Add(bzSeg);

            pthFigure.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection;

            if (pthFigureCollection == null)
                pthFigureCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
            pthFigureCollection.Add(pthFigure);
            PreviousContactPoint = CurrentContactPoint;
       }
    }
```

And code in pointer released event.

```
List<UIElement> uielementscolctn = new List<UIElement>();
           foreach(var item in _drawCanvas.Children)
           {
               var x = item as Line;

               uielementscolctn.Add(x);
           }
           foreach (var uielenmt in uielementscolctn)
           {
               _drawCanvas.Children.Remove(uielenmt);
           }
            PathGeometry pthGeometry = new PathGeometry();
            pthGeometry.Figures = pthFigureCollection;
            arcPath = new Path();
           arcPath.Tapped+=arcPath_Tapped;
            translateTransform_ = new TranslateTransform();
            translateTransform_.X = 0.0;
            translateTransform_.Y = 0.0;

            scaleTransform_ = new ScaleTransform();
            scaleTransform_.ScaleX = 0.0;
            scaleTransform_.ScaleY = 0.0;




            arcPath.ManipulationMode = MarkupBase.manipulationMode_;

            arcPath.ManipulationStarted += arcPath_ManipulationStarted;
            arcPath.ManipulationDelta += arcPath_ManipulationDelta;
            arcPath.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Violet);
            arcPath.StrokeThickness = 5;

            arcPath.Data = pthGeometry;

            originalBounds_ = arcPath.Data.Bounds;
            _drawCanvas.Children.Add(arcPath);
             arcPath.Data.Transform = tgroup;
            PenID = 0;
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Arrow, 1);
            pthFigureCollection = null;
```

unable to manipulate the path shape, because when ever I changed value as arcPath.Data.Transform = tgroup; the data bounds of path become zero.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to look at InkCanvas ? This is the way to do what you want, even in UWP apps.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inkcanvas.aspx

Comment: InkCanvas is not available for windows8.1 apps. Could we manipulate a Path(shape).

Comment: My idea is making the all stokes as path and make manipulation operations  for that path

Comment: Why are you talking about Windows 8.1 ? Is it the target OS ?

Comment: it is the target o.s. The app is windows store app.

Comment: OK but which target OS ? Windows 8 ? Windows 8.1 ? Windows 10 ?

If this is Windows 10 (UWP), InkCanvas is the way to go.

Comment: It should support Windows8.1, windows10 and Windows 10(UWP).

Comment: I have developed the drawing using BezierSegment with out using inkmanager. I can able to draw anything on canvas, but I am unable to manipulate on canvas. here is my code , under _drawCanvas_PointerMoved event calling addpencil method as follows

Comment: void AddPencil(Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
              PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(_drawCanvas);

                CurrentContactPoint = pt.Position;
                X1 = PreviousContactPoint.X;
                Y1 = PreviousContactPoint.Y;
                X2 = CurrentContactPoint.X;
                Y2 = CurrentContactPoint.Y;

Comment: if (Distance(X1, Y1, X2, Y2) > 2.0)
                {
                    Line line = new Line()
                      {
                          X1 = X1,
                          Y1 = Y1,
                          X2 = X2,
                          Y2 = Y2,
                          StrokeThickness = 5,
                          Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Violet)
                      };
                    _drawCanvas.Children.Add(line);
                }

Comment: PathFigure pthFigure = new PathFigure();
                pthFigure.StartPoint = PreviousContactPoint;
                BezierSegment bzSeg = new BezierSegment();
                Point p1 = new Point();
                p1.X = X1;
                p1.Y = Y1;
                Point p2 = new Point();
                p2.X = X2;
                p2.Y = Y2;
                bzSeg.Point1 = p1;
                  bzSeg.Point2 =p2;
                  bzSeg.Point3 = CurrentContactPoint;

Comment: PathSegmentCollection myPathSegmentCollection = new PathSegmentCollection();
                myPathSegmentCollection.Add(bzSeg);

                pthFigure.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection;

                if (pthFigureCollection == null)
                    pthFigureCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
                pthFigureCollection.Add(pthFigure);
                PreviousContactPoint = CurrentContactPoint;
                   }

Comment: and in pointer released event the code as follows                                                  foreach(var item in _drawCanvas.Children)
               {
                   var x = item as Line;
                   uielementscolctn.Add(x);
               }
               foreach (var uielenmt in uielementscolctn)
               {
                   _drawCanvas.Children.Remove(uielenmt);
               }
                PathGeometry pthGeometry = new PathGeometry();
                pthGeometry.Figures = pthFigureCollection;
                arcPath = new Path();

Comment: translateTransform_ = new TranslateTransform();
                translateTransform_.X = 0.0;
                translateTransform_.Y = 0.0;

                scaleTransform_ = new ScaleTransform();
                scaleTransform_.ScaleX = 0.0;
                scaleTransform_.ScaleY = 0.0;

Comment: arcPath.ManipulationMode = MarkupBase.manipulationMode_;

                arcPath.ManipulationStarted += arcPath_ManipulationStarted;
                arcPath.ManipulationDelta += arcPath_ManipulationDelta;
                arcPath.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Violet);
                arcPath.StrokeThickness = 5;

                arcPath.Data = pthGeometry;
              
                originalBounds_ = arcPath.Data.Bounds;
                _drawCanvas.Children.Add(arcPath);
               //  arcPath.Data.Transform = tgroup;
                PenID = 0;

Comment: Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Arrow, 1);
                pthFigureCollection = null;

Comment: but I am unable to manipulate the path canvas, the manipulationa delta event got hit.

Answer (score 0):

Use polyline segment instead of bezier segment.